# Check for double tap in editing mode

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, theos

I'm making a tweak that involves popping an alert whenever the user double taps an icon in editing mode. I've tried hooking on to

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

of `SBIcon` and then

```
{
    %orig;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (touch.tapCount == 2 && [[objc_getClass("SBIconController") sharedInstance] isEditing])
    {
        //pop an alert and do stuff
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work at all. Could anyone tell me what is wrong with the above and suggest alternative ways to achieve this?

EDIT: I'm using theos, if it matters.

Comment: Just FYI, instead of `objc_getClass()` use `NSClassFromString()` which takes an object of type `NSString`. It's a bit safer.

Comment: Or actually, instead I might recommend using `@class SBIconController;` at the top of your implementation file since you seem to assume that the class will exist at runtime anyway, and then just straight up `[SBIconController sharedInstance]`. `NSClassFromString()` and `objc_getClass()` are more useful for dynamically composed class names, and not using them avoids the lookup time.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use Tap gesture recognizer.It is more specific and works very accurately.

For more info you can check out this link:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html

Comment: Thanks. But which method would I hook on to to add the UITapGestureRecogniser?

Comment: This link will help you...  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UITapGestureRecognizer   and you can find a sample project on this link... https://github.com/jamessa/SimpleGestureRecognizers    hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Alternative ways for you

If your icon is a button then you can easily detect the Double tab by adding `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat` event

```
[yourIconButton addTarget:self action:@selector(multipleTap:withEvent:) 
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];



-(IBAction)multipleTap:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event 
{
   UITouch* touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
   if (touch.tapCount == 2) {
     // Do all your actions here
   }
}
```

If you are considering it for a whole view then use UITapGesture

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[yourIconView addGestureRecognizer:tap];


- (void)tapAction:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    //Do your action
}
```